# How to call my function in Bootstrap Checkout example?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function () {
  'use strict'

  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation')

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
  }, false)
}())

// Where do I have to call myfunction?
function myFunction (){
  alert('All Values are valid');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="container">
  <div class="py-5 text-center">
    <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="/docs/4.3/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
    <h2>Checkout form</h2>
    <p class="lead">Below is an example form built entirely with Bootstrap’s form controls. Each required form group has a validation state that can be triggered by attempting to submit the form without completing it.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
      <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
        <span class="text-muted">Your cart</span>
        <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span>
      </h4>
      <ul class="list-group mb-3">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <div>
            <h6 class="my-0">Product name</h6>
            <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-muted">$12</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <div>
            <h6 class="my-0">Second product</h6>
            <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-muted">$8</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <div>
            <h6 class="my-0">Third item</h6>
            <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-muted">$5</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between bg-light">
          <div class="text-success">
            <h6 class="my-0">Promo code</h6>
            <small>EXAMPLECODE</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-success">-$5</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
          <span>Total (USD)</span>
          <strong>$20</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <form class="card p-2">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Promo code">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Redeem</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
      <h4 class="mb-3">Billing address</h4>
      <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Valid first name is required.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Valid last name is required.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
              Your username is required.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="email">Email <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="address">Address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="1234 Main St" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please enter your shipping address.
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="address2">Address 2 <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2" placeholder="Apartment or suite">
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>United States</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please select a valid country.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="state" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>California</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please provide a valid state.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="zip">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Zip code required.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="same-address">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="same-address">Shipping address is the same as my billing address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="save-info">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="save-info">Save this information for next time</label>
        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4">

        <h4 class="mb-3">Payment</h4>

        <div class="d-block my-3">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input id="credit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" checked required>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="credit">Credit card</label>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input id="debit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="debit">Debit card</label>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input id="paypal" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="paypal">PayPal</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="cc-name">Name on card</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-name" placeholder="" required>
            <small class="text-muted">Full name as displayed on card</small>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Name on card is required
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-number" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Credit card number is required
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="cc-expiration">Expiration</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-expiration" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Expiration date required
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="cc-cvv">CVV</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Security code required
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Continue to checkout</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="my-5 pt-5 text-muted text-center text-small">
    <p class="mb-1">&copy; 2017-2019 Company Name</p>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Hello!

I try to call my function in the [Bootstrap example "Checkout"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/checkout/) example when all necessary input fields are ok.

But I don't understand where I have to call myfunction in the bootstrap example javascript code.

Myfunction should be called when all nessesary fields are ok and the form should be send.

See the code snippet below.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: novalidate bypass validation

Comment: Can you explain your answer, please?

Comment: ok , no its fine novalidate by pass form validation, but you have js validation, so it only do js validations. where ae you calling myFunction()

Comment: So where do I have to call myFunction in the code? Can you show me a working example please?